# Cómo saber la estructura de un archivo para hacer una aplicación en Java que lo pueda abrir?

Tags: java

Si quisiera hacer una aplicación Java que abriera un archivo con extensión pdf, xlsx, sql, mp3 o jpg, que se necesita para lograr tal fin?
Hay documentación que explique como es la estructura de estos archivos?Por ejemplo, cómo hizo Libreoffice para poder abrir los archivos de microsoft excel .xlsx para poderlos trabajar en calc?
Gracias.

Comment: hay documentación de todo, solo es cuestión de buscar :D

Comment: Me gustaría añadir al comentario de Christian, que aunque es cierto que hay documentación de todo, hay veces, sobre todo con el software cerrado, que no encuentras la totalidad de esa documentación porque está cerrada al público, entonces lo que se usa es ingeniería inversa, busca sobre ello si te encuentras una puerta cerrada.